# android element below list is gone when the list fills the screen

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-layout, android-listview

I have a `LinearLayhout` that contains a listView and below it an `ImageButton`.
When I add items to the list, the `imageButton` is moving lower and lower, which is what I want but when there are many elements in the list so that is the list is big enough to fill the screen, I can scroll down to the bottom of the list, but no further, meaning I can't see the `imageButton` anymore.

**Code:**

```
<LinearLayout  
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/add_interest_layout_root"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/back" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:divider="@drawable/downa"
           android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
           android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginTop="6dp" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </ListView>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout16">
        <ImageButton          
              android:src="@drawable/add" 
              android:id="@+id/btn_interest_more" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"></ImageButton>
        <TextView 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/TextView08"                
              android:text="be more\nspecific"   
              android:gravity="center"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to see the `ImageButto`n even when I scroll down.

Comment: just fix the listview height and try, Eg:android:layout_height="300dp"

Comment: never add an absolute size for views in Android. The above suggestion is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something like this. Mind you this is a pseudo code so you better fill the correct attributes.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/add_interest_layout_root"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/back" android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
          android:gravity="center" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
          <!-- LinearLayout elements same as above -->
      </LinearLayout>

      <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
          android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:divider="@drawable/downa"
          android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
          android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginTop="6dp" android:layout_height="match_parent">
      </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks PravinCG, your solution worked!
i ended up using 
View footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null, false);
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
because i wanted the list to have android:layout_height="match_parent" (because when it is on "wrap_content" the getView of my ListAdapter is called twice...).
so in order to have match_parent on the one hand, and the item below the list stitched to the list, on the other hand i added this added this item as last element in the list as its footer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is exactly the solution to your problem: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/ which is solved by setting fillviewport on your listview.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your LinearLayout that holds the ImageButton

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

**UPDATE:**

Forget the above code. I misunderstand you. Sorry.

Do this instead: Add this layout as your root layout

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <!-- Your code -->

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: That attribute is available for RelativeLayout as I have posted in my answer. LinearLayout does not have it and simply ignores it.